# .Net Core / Console Application / Configuration / XML

Tags: c#, configuration, console-application, .net-core

My first little venture into the .Net Core libraries using the new ConfigurationBuilder, and Options pattern.

Lot's of good examples here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html
and a good copy of the example [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/May/23/Strongly-Typed-Configuration-Settings-in-ASPNET-Core)

Item 1. it says this can be used with non MVC applications, but no examples on how to use it without MVC - particularly if you are using a custom, strongly-typed class.  **I would like to see an example of showing the setup of DependencyInjection, Configuration, and Logging using a Console application**.

Item 2. it says you can write back, but no examples or documentation as to how to persist any changes back to the file store.  **I would like to see an example of how persist changes back into the configuration using a strongly typed class.  In both Json or XML?**

Item 3. all examples require a hand bombed initial file - **would like to see an example where the initial json/xml file is created from a strongly-typed class** (comes in handy when there are many parameters for the application).

If I can spend enough time on this (rather than re-post an example already in the documentation) I'll do it!  **If you know of a post/documentation that will help me, I would appreciate it.**

Comment: You say you have question, but I don't see any question, only complaining about missing examples. If you're asking for those examples, then that's not what SO is for.

Comment: I can' find any examples or documentation what I'm looking for, I'm hoping that another developer can point me in the right direction, or point me to some documentation.

Comment: Microsoft welcomes the community to write up such topics on its documentation sites as well as Stack Overflow Documentation. You might keep an eye on them or raise a request there. A fast moving platform like this makes it boring to document, so I am not surprised that many things are missing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**How do I configure a .NET Core 1.0.0 Console Application for Dependency Injection, Logging and Configuration?**

A lot of what was written is deprecated after RC2. (see [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/106)).
Fortunatelly there are some updated posts with excelent info:

[Essential .NET - Dependency Injection with .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707534.aspx)

[Essential .NET - Logging with .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt694089.aspx)

I came up with the following solution. I bet there are things that can be improved, please leave comments so I can improve this answer.

In my `static void Main`, I

- Setup Dependency injection
- Invoke `ConfigureServices`
- Instantiate my `Application` class using DI
- Switch from 'sync Main' to '**async** Application.Run()' 
  (It makes sense to me to switch to async as soon as possible and only once.)

On my `Application` Class:

- I inject as much as possible on the class constructor.
- Catch any exception on the Run() method.

Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

        // Application application = new Application(serviceCollection);
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var app = serviceProvider.GetService<Application>();

        // For async
        Task.Run(() => app.Run()).Wait(); // Exceptions thrown here will be lost! Catch them all at Run()
        // Otherwise use sync as in: app.Run();            
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddConsole()
            .AddDebug();

        services.AddSingleton(loggerFactory); // Add first my already configured instance
        services.AddLogging(); // Allow ILogger<T>

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = GetConfiguration();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(configuration);

        // Support typed Options
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<MyOptions>(configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));  

        services.AddTransient<Application>();
    }

    private static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
    {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .Build();
    }
}

public class MyOptions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    ILogger _logger;
    MyOptions _settings;

    public Application(ILogger<Application> logger, IOptions<MyOptions> settings)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _settings = settings.Value;
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"This is a console application for {_settings.Name}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

The AppSettings.json file:

```
{
  "MyOptions": {
    "Name" : "John"
  }
}
```

And the `project.json` file:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
```

On your question #2: I've read the document and unless I am missing something, it does not says you can write configuration. I'm not sure you can do that, unless you edit the JSON files manually using Newtonsoft.JSON.

> If a
>   name/value pair is written to Configuration, it is not persisted. This
>   means that the written value will be lost when the sources are read
>   again.

For your question #3 I've included a default AppSettings.json file. Your config should have a Section where its settings match by name to the public properties of your settings class.

Comment: What is really missing from the Article link, is the Using statements (and related NuGet packages needed) to gain access to the extension methods. Lesson learned - be wary of extension methods in .Net core!

Comment: Still fighting with reading from an XML file, as opposed to JSON.  Ryan Crawford tweeted me to include .Extention.Configuration.XML, but I'm getting a UTF-16 exception (unable to convert?).

Comment: wow I havent seen UTF-16 for a while... Things to check is your text file encoding (on notepad: save as -> Encoding) and your `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` tag. I suggest to start with a plain simple XML file created with notepad or vi first. (do not copy paste, just type). Once that is working, try to increase the xml.

Comment: Is the XML configuration? or is it just data? you can read it with `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` also.

Comment: Check out sample XML configuration usage sample here: http://whereslou.com/2014/05/23/asp-net-vnext-moving-parts-iconfiguration/

Comment: Gerardo - based on your blog, I got rid of the error by simply removing the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> from the top of the XML.  I created this XML by serializing a class through XmlSerializXML.  This class is going to be representative of a large configuration file - one class, with a number of properties - and I would like to rehydrate the class on startup.  My theory is that if the file is not there it can be created by serializing out a class with default values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120060/discussion-between-gerardo-grignoli-and-codputer).

Comment: Would be nice to have an update of that for .net core 2.0

Comment: I got null value at `var app = serviceProvider.GetService<Application>()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928025/net-core-2-0-console-program-got-null-value-when-running-serviceprovider-getse