# .Net core 2.0 console program got null value when running `serviceProvider.GetService<Application>();`?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

The following .Net core 2.0 console application got null value when running `serviceProvider.GetService<Application>();`?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services);
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var app = serviceProvider.GetService<Application>(); // Got null value
        Task.Run(() => app.Run()).Wait();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddConsole()
            .AddDebug();

        services.AddSingleton(loggerFactory); // Add first my already configured instance
        services.AddLogging(); // Allow ILogger<T>

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = GetConfiguration();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(configuration);

        // Support typed Options
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<MyOptions>(configuration.GetSection("MyOptions")); // Error!

        services.AddTransient<Application>();
    }

    private static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
    {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddXmlFile("App.config", optional: true).Build();
    }

    public class MyOptions
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Application
    {
        ILogger _logger;
        MyOptions _settings;

        public Application(ILogger<Application> logger, IOptions<MyOptions> settings)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _settings = settings.Value;
        }

        public async Task Run()
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"This is a console application for {_settings.Name}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it looks good, you just need to provide a singleton for your options.

```
var options = new MyOptions();
configuration.GetSection("MyOptions").Bind(options);
services.AddSingleton<MyOptions>(options);
```

Then, shift your app to use that singleton.

```
public Application(ILogger<Application> logger, MyOptions settings)
```

**EDIT: What about IOptions Pattern?**

Seems like others have suggested that you can use that syntax if you import         the 1.0.0-rc2-final version of Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions, but that will cascade into other references as well.  Might not be worth it just to late-bind the options class.

**All Working (less IOptions)**

If that's an ok approach, then there is some other code in that section that doesn't function.  Cleaned up version below.  Hope that helps.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services);
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var app = serviceProvider.GetService<Application>(); // Got null value
        Task.Run(() => app.Run()).Wait();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
             .AddConsole() // Error!
             .AddDebug();

        services.AddSingleton(loggerFactory); // Add first my already configured instance
        services.AddLogging(); // Allow ILogger<T>

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = GetConfiguration();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(configuration);

        // Support typed Options
        var myOptions = new MyOptions();
        configuration.GetSection("MyOptions").Bind(myOptions);
        services.AddSingleton<MyOptions>(myOptions);

        services.AddTransient<Application>();
    }

    private static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration() {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddXmlFile("App.config", optional: true).Build();
    }

    public class MyOptions {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Application {
        ILogger _logger;
        MyOptions _settings;

        public Application(ILogger<Application> logger, MyOptions settings) {
            _logger = logger;
            _settings = settings;
        }

        public async Task Run() {
            try {
                _logger.LogInformation($"This is a console application for {_settings.Name}");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, I found the code in another question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38706959/net-core-console-applicatin-configuration-xml?noredirect=1&lq=1. Is it the best to do set up a .Net core console application for logging and configure? Visual Studio actually complaints at the Method `public async Task Run()` of `Application` that there is no await in the method.Or I should define my first method as `async` so it can be used as `await` in the `Run()`?

Comment: Yeah - they changed the way you add configs between rc1 and now  (I like this better - because that goofy IOptions interface doesn't end up snaking through your entire codebase).  On async - you couldn't make Main (console entry) async once upon a time... not sure if .net core allows it.  So - wrapping it in a Task.Run makes sense.  On a simpler note:  if that RUN method doesnt need to be async, then just declare it public void Run() instead... Sorry if that's too obvious to mention ;)

Comment: BTW, I plan to store the connection string to the `App.config` file. And the scaffolded Context.cs file will use the connection string. What's the best practice to handle the connection string in the code above?

Comment: config has a specific property for ConnectionStrings.  Not sure what you guys are using for an erm package, but we use Dapper and store a ConnectionFactory object in the DI pipeline (instead of a connection string).  Then - when we need to do unit tests, its easy to swap out database for a mocking layer or for SQLite.  DI is there so you can INJECT -- if you're not going to inject, then I dont get why you'd add that level of complexity to your codebase.  I look at ditching the db in unit tests as a base-level DI use-case.